# Mitigating session hijacking in java for an https request

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, https, session-cookies

I have already set `useHttpOnly=true` in tomcat context.xml and is using a self-signed certificate generated using java keytool in server.xml connector element support to support SSL as follows :

context.xml

```
<Context useHttpOnly="true">
<!-- other code -->
</Context>
```

server.xml

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
            maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
            clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
            keystoreFile="my key file location"
            keystorePass="keystore password" />
```

After restarting the server, I have confirmed that the changes have taken effect using chrome dev tools :

[image]:

I guess this doesn't actually make the site immune to session hijacking since if an attacker were able to get the a valid session ID by sniffing. If a user is made to authenticate himself with a known session ID, and then hijacking the user-validated session by the knowledge of the used session ID. The attacker can then provide a legitimate web application session ID and try to make the victim's browser use it.

I have tested this using burp suite by sniffing the session ID of a user(with admin role) and use it as a  the session ID of a user having another role. The server wasn't able to recognize whether the active session request is from the original device or an attacker who is illegitimately using the session. I guess this is where SSL comes in! The browser doesn't trust my self-signed certificate and this makes me wonder how different it would be if I use other SSL's. Does it actually make my site more secure than the self-signed certificate? Or is it just the trustworthiness of certificates if you look from the browser's perspective? Is there any way for the server to check whether the request is coming from the authenticated user and not an attacker who hijacked the session?

Comment: *if an attacker were able to get the a valid session ID by sniffing* How is an attacker "sniffing" a valid session ID from encrypted traffic? As far as not trusting your self-signed certificate, the issue is whether users will trust your site; it adds **zero** extra protection against sniffing attacks. BTW, SSL is more properly called Transport Layer Security (TLS) - it can be used to add encryptions to any TCP protocol (not just HTTP). You can use TLS to do some [interesting](https://www.stunnel.org/) things.

Comment: "the issue is whether users will trust your site; it adds zero extra protection against sniffing attacks" -- Yes, but other than that, is there any difference as far as certificates are concerned? "if an attacker were able to get the a valid session ID by sniffing How is an attacker "sniffing" a valid session ID from encrypted traffic" -- I have used burp suite to intercept the traffic and was able to get all the data that was transferred in the request.

Comment: *is there any difference as far as certificates are concerned?* **no**. And man in the middle attacks are only possible if the end user can't validate your certificate. The usual way to do that is with a signed certificate. But if an attacker can also generate a valid signed certificate, then yes; you would still be vulnerable to a man in the middle attack. This is not **new**.

Comment: I think I have understood the need for a valid certificate and it  as it seems that a valid certificate doesn't  necessarily mean that the attacker can't compromise the user session. Is there a way to check it in the server side on whether the request was compromised?

Comment: Sure. Valid certificate on client, valid certificate on server, perform two way validation. Now every client must be validated. The cryptographic literature is quite good, or you could keep asking strangers on the internet to explain math to you.

Answer (score 0):

> The attacker can then provide a legitimate web application session ID and try to make the victim's browser use it

The above is called [session fixation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation).

To mitigate session fixation after successful login, store the user information temporarily, invalidate the current session, create a new session, copy the user information to the new session.

By this if the attacker used the session id which he generated that session wont be the victim's session.

Comment: This was already done using spring's own session management configuration. The session ID changes after logging in. My problem is that the attacker already have a valid session ID with him and makes another logged in victim use it.